# How to stop list output using foreach parallel look in R

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

I am running a foreach loop where I want to read in data, modify it, and output the files in parallel. It works fine, but I always get output of a list of the files after the loop finishes.  If I include rm(data) in the loop, the data is gone, but a list of empty data frames is output.  Here's a generalization of my code:

```
foreach (f = 1:100, .packages = c('lubridate','vroom','readr')) %dopar% {
   data <- vroom(file)

   # manipulate data

   write_csv(data, file = output_file)
   rm(data)}
```

The issue is that I am getting a list of the empty data frames (since I removed them using rm(data)).

```
+   rm(data)
+   
+ }
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL
```

What do I have to do to get rid of this extra, unneeded output?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get NULL because it is the last output (from rm()).
You can either use .combine = 'c' to get only one NULL or wrap the call of foreach in a invisible().

Comment: Thanks.  Isn't there a way to suppress all of that output?  All I want it do is read the data, manipulate the data, and write it out.  I don't understand why it's outputting everything like it is.

Comment: @user8229029 This by design. It's functional programming. See it as a pipeline. What you do is side effect that is something that is not provided by function input or is not returned as result. For what you are expecting look at `purrr`'s `walk` function and it's parallel version using `furrr`, `furrr_walk`. Otherwise as replied above you need to explicitly ignore returned vales.

Comment: You get the output of foreach that is printed in the console because you don't assign it to a variable, and don't use invisible().

Answer (score 0):

```
junk_output = foreach (f = 1:100, .packages = c('lubridate','vroom','readr')) %dopar% {
   data <- vroom(file)

   # manipulate data

   write_csv(data, file = output_file)
   rm(data)}
```

The junk_output will capture the return and not fill your console.